# Matching rows based on column value python pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, match, row

I am working with financial data and I want to match timestamps of two stocks. The format I have (or can generate) is:

A big dataframe with columns `[timestamp1, ..., timestamp2, ....]` or two seperate `dataframe` with columns `[timestamp1, ..] [timestamp2, ...]` with index type `integer`.

I want to get a big `dataframe` with only rows where `timestamp1 = timestamp2`, and do note that it is possible that 
`df['timestamp1][i] == df['timestamp2][j]` where `i!=j`

A sample dataframe could be:

```
2018-01-02-07:00:00, salmon, bacon, eggs,  2018-01-02-07:01:00, peanuts, butter, milk

2018-01-02-07:03:00, tuna, avocado, null,  2018-01-02-07:02:00, bacon, bacon, bacon

2018-01-02-07:04:00, salmon, tuna, tuna,  2018-01-02-07:03:00, lettuce, tomato, bacon
```

As you can see, this is not solvable by
`df = df[ df['timestamp1] == df['timestamp2'] ]` since the index of the corresponding timestamps is not equal. **Note that the index type is int**

I do know a very tedious way to solve it but it must be possible in an easier way (e.g. one could solve by filling up all non existent timestamps such that the index number of each timestamp will be the same)

Hope you can help me out, I will be forever in your debt!

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] including an example output you want, it will be a lot easier for people to understand what you want and fiddle around to find a solution. You can [edit] your question to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2 separate dataframes:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="timestamp1", right_on="timestamp2", how="inner")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the timestamps in two columns of the same dataframe, you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first find the common values
common = np.intersect1d(df.timestamp1, df.timestamp2)

# now get rows that have these common values
df[df.timestamp1.isin(common) | df.timestamp2.isin(common)]
```